# Does cheat engine contain any viruses?

Tags: malware, exploit, virus

So today I was about to download cheat engine to access some hidden mini games on PvZ Game of the year edition, and I want to know; is it safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know if what you have downloaded is actually safe. But, a common way to distribute malware are social attacks, where the user itself is downloading and executing the malware and thus implicitly helps the malware to bypass safe guards which are only effective against unintended downloads.

For example it might be claimed that this is an important update or that the software  promises to offer features the user wants (like in the case of cheat software). And sometimes the downloaded software seems to actually do something useful, only that the bundled malware is running in the background unnoticed by the user.

Comment: ok during the install it asked me to install extra programs so I cancelled

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be 100% sure if anything is safe. You can check the file with your own antivirus and you can also submit the file to the virus total website which will run it through multiple antivirus engines. By that time of course it's too late as you've downloaded the file and potentially infected your machine.

If you do not want to go to the trouble of downloading the file in a sandbox and verifying it, the safer option is not to download a file where you have suspicions it may be unsafe. If you do,  ensure virus signatures are up to date and you have a recent working backup.